# Viewport does not work

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm trying to scale my website correctly on mobile, however when I use the viewport meta tag it does nothing.

My design is around 500px wide (and I do not want it to scale down, so I would like the website to "zoom" out until the whole design fits the page if the users width is below 500px) so optimally I would want to do something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500">
```

or:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height" />
```

Even when I try to change the values nothing happens, like it's not working at all.

What can I do?

Comment: What mobile devices and browsers are you testing on? What version of the operating system? What version of the browser?

Comment: Without the required example markup that shows the problem, anything we say will only be a wild guess but setting the width for viewport is a unique thing to do. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i'm not getting your question do you want your website page to be zoomed and fit into mobile view correctly OR want to view full Entire page in mobile view.-- @osk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the page to be zoomed to the viewport and not be responsive (i.e. look the same as on a larger device, but displayed smaller). In this case, just *remove* all viewport meta tags - mobile devices will do the zooming automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
meta http-equiv='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
```

And avoid using:

```
height=device-height
```

Because: When size is already declared as the user screen size, we don't need to declare height again. In that case, the aspect ratio (especially of images) would alter. They might stretch or squeeze.